# Installing php-5.2.14 using yum

Tags: php, yum

I'd love to go back to php version 5.2.x using yum so I can compile it using PHC.  I'm having issues finding an old version, though.  Can someone please give me instructions on installing php-5.2.x using yum on my system or tell me where to find the repositories to do it?

Comment: I asked a similar question that might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/104323/how-can-i-downgrade-my-version-of-php

Answer (score 1):

A workaround using rpm without yum:
1. Download the PHP RPM files manually.
2. Run something like:

`rpm -Uvh php-5.2.14 (and other php dependencies) --oldpackage`

The --oldpackage flag will downgrade the version gracefully.